# LUKS/clevis fstab: "A start job is running for dev-mapper-encryptedfs.device (5min / no limit)"

Tags: boot, fstab, luks, cryptsetup

Anyone know who can describe how to get dev-mapper stop halting boot? (LUKS/clevis with /etc/fstab entry)

I've setup'ed clevis9 / LUKS with late boot authentication

```
sudo systemctl enable clevis-luks-askpass.path
```

Without any /etc/fstab entry, Ubuntu boots and unlocks the device.

With /dev/mapper entry in /etc/fstab, Ubuntu boot hangs forever with message:

```
A start job is running for dev-mapper-encryptedfs.device (5min / no limit)
```

The following **/etc/fstab**:

```
UUID=137541e1-4ee0-11e8-b9f6-d45ddf136996 / ext4 defaults 0 0
UUID=F9E1-7C3E /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 0 /swap.img    none    swap    sw  0   0
/dev/mapper/encryptedfs /home/user/luks/encryptedfs ext4    defaults,x-systemd-device-timeout=10   0       0
```

works OK for normal use, but not boot.

For reference, this is the **/etc/crypttab**

```
encryptedfs /dev/sda3 none _netdev
```

EDIT **RESOLUTION**: /etc/fstab entry for /dev/mapper/encryptedfs needed to specify _netdev also.

Comment: I think what is going on is the normal boot process with systemd-fstab-generator that tries to unlock your /dev/mapper/encryptedfs as if it is a normal LUKS partition. May be _netdev is not recognized ? Or may need more configuration?

Comment: @solsTiCe I think _netdev is understood because /etc/crypttab entry without /etc/fstab entry works (luks asks for password and clevis provides unlock).

Comment: I don't know but I know for sure I got the same error message, when for an unkown reason, I got `/etc/fstab` setup to use an encrypted volume while `/etc/crypttab` was left empty. Changes not saved. Just standard LUKs not clevis one.

Comment: @solsTiCe _netdev was needed in /etc/fstab also ^_^

Answer (score 2):

**RESOLVED!**

/etc/fstab entry also needed _netdev, i.e.

```
/dev/mapper/encryptedfs /home/user/luks/encryptedfs ext4    defaults,x-systemd-device-timeout=10,_netdev   0       0
```

I think what was happing with the old configuration;

- clevis required _netdev
- /etc/cryptab entry /dev/mapper/encryptedfs required _netdev
- /etc/fstab entry started before _netdev but depeded on /dev/mapper/encryptedfs
- i.e. process started before _netdev, waited on _netdev, and prevented _netdev from starting
- ***deadlock***